# Añadir productos jQuery y que al hacer clic en otros los pueda sumar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$(function () {
    $("article").click (function() {
    $("#carrito").show();
    var productes = $(this).text();
    $("#carritoproductes").text(productes);
   });
});
```

Si hago clic en un producto, me lo añade sin problema pero si intento meter otro este desaparece y me añade el otro

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer`$("#carritoproductes").text(productes);` Siempre vas a sustituir el texto que tenga el elemento con id carritoproductes. Si quieres que se mantenga lo anterior puedes utilizar la función `append`. Con esto en vez de sustituir texto, añades lo que quieras al final. Prueba este ejemlo:

```js
$(function () {
    $("article").click (function() {
       $("#carrito").show();
       var productes = $(this).text();
       $("#carritoproductes").append(productes + "<br/>");
   });
});
```

```css
article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline;
}

#carrito {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2em 1em 1em 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.titulo {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article>ARTICULO 1</article>
<article>ARTICULO 2</article>
<div id="carrito" style="display: none;">
  <div class="titulo">CARRITO</div>
  <div id="carritoproductes"></div>
</div>
```

Más info:

- https://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Muchísimas Gracias Roger! No conocía la opción de "append" soy nuevo en esto y supongo que con 
 lo que hacemos es bajar una fila los resultados esta genial gracias de nuevo